# Как изменить свойства элемента управления внутри DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-datagrid

У меня есть DataGrid, в нем 5 столбцов. Ячейки последнего столбца содержат RadTimeBar. Вопрос в следующем :как я могу программно, не через xaml изменить свойство этого элемента RadTimeBar?
Допустим, при загрузки приложения из access задаются значения для свойства SelectionStart и SelectionEnd этого самого элемента RadTimeBar[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Простите, что вторгаюсь в личную жизнь, но вы привязками (Binding) пользуетесь?

Comment: @Андрей NOP да, все колонки записят от коллекции. А как прибиндить свойство элемента, находящегося в datagrid через DataTemplate к коллекции? Через c# не могу обратиться к элементу, его попросту не видно

Comment: Покажите разметку

Comment: @Андрей NOP извиняюсь за скрин. Сейчас с телефона сижу, пока что нет доступа к компьютеру

Comment: Ну у вас там есть привязка к DateStart, вот и меняйте этот DateStart при необходимости, через привязку изменение подхватится и отобразится в UI (если вы не забыли про INotifyPropertyChanged)